# Send value to next page not working

Tags: php, html

Good day!

I have a form where I have first name and last name but I am sending the first name value only in same field on next page like code below

```
<label>Owned By:</label>
                <br />
                <input class="input" type="text" name="ownerPrint" readonly value="<?php echo (isset($_GET['first_name'])) ? htmlentities($_GET['first_name']) : ''; ?>"/>
```

This works first for first name. How can I do the same for last_name in same line? Becuase above html code is one field with label owned by and this should show both first and last names concatenated

**Code which is coming from previous file**

```
echo '<td class="forscreen"><a href="equipments.php?emp_number=' .$row['emp_number'] .'&first_name='.$row['first_name'] .'&last_name='.$row['last_name'] .'&department='.$row['department'] . '">Add Accessories</a></td>';
```

Comment: Could you share code of `last_name` input?

Comment: Put both parameter in url for second page.   www.site.com?first_name=abc&second_name=xyz.

Comment: code which is coming from previous file is editted now

Comment: copy and just replace first_name with second_name

Comment: `var_dump( $_GET );` Make sure the get is there on the next page

Comment: there in no complication between first_name and last_name just copy paste and replace index with last_name instead of first_name

Comment: NO I want both appear check the html it has only one i.e. first_name if i remove first name then last will be only shown

Comment: Question Modified @JYoThI

Comment: @Confused Question Modified

Comment: @Blinkydamo I Modified the question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concatenate the two inputs:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['first_name'], $_GET['last_name'])) {
    $full_name = htmlentities($_GET['first_name'] . " " . $_GET['last_name']);
} else {
    $full_name = '';
}
?>
```

Then use `$full_name` in the `value` attribute of the input:

```
<input class="input" type="text" name="ownerPrint" readonly value="<?php echo $full_name; ?>"/>
```

Comment: No No I dont want to do this .. just tel me concatenation which I did above. using & sign

Comment: `&` is for separating two different input parameters. You can't use it in a single input field.